# Redirection of electric current in a circuit

Tags: current, dc, boost

I'm new in electrical engineering so apologies if I sound like an idiot but I just can get this question out of my head.

[image]

Suppose you have a DC fan running which is powered by a battery. The specifications of the fan or battery are unnecessary but let's just say the fan is 3W and 6V. We will take electron flow to represent the way the current flows. Now the current will flow from the negative terminal and the electron will arrive at the positive terminal. The question is **Why can't you just connect it to the negative terminal again?** If voltage/potential difference is the issue, a boost-converter can easily solve that. Now all that is left is to add some capacitors to smooth out the current. I've attached a picture of what I proposed. I know the diode side are opposite so don't mind them and the both transistor are controlled by a microcontroller which I purposely didn't draw to prevent it from getting complicated. The mc is also powered by the same battery.
Will appreciate if someone could give an answer while not roasting the hell out of a noob.

Comment: There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar. Add in a diagram of your proposal. There's a battery symbol and you can use the LAMP symbol for the motor. Alternatively draw it out and post a sharp, cropped photo. "*Why can't you just connect it to the negative terminal again?*" What is "**it**" in this sentence?

Comment: Got it. Will do.

Comment: Fail! Image not sharp, not cropped, too low resolution and wrong orientation. Try again.

Comment: What is that postage-stamp sized thing in your question? This is an EE site and the default is to use conventional current flow. Current does not flow from the negative terminal. If you insist on talking about electron flow then electrons flow from the negative terminal not current.

Comment: C1 and C2 are DC blocking. Your DC motor cannot run with those in circuit. Why would you need two in series anyway? You need to add in the return path from the transistor. NPN transistors are not MOSFETs - they're a completely different type. D1 is in the wrong orientation if it is to allow current to return to the battery negative. Both ends of C4 are connected together so it does nothing.

Comment: by npn meant n channel mosfet. Why would c1 and c2 block the current but i guess i can only use one capacitor there in parallel. D1 is there to prevent the current from returning to negative terminal. The circuit is meant to redirect the current coming out of the motor back into the circuit as the inductor provides the emf

Comment: The capacitor symbol represents the two isolated plates of a capacitor with air or another insulator between them. DC current cannot flow between the plates. It seems as though you are trying to design a perpetual motion machine.

Comment: Something like that. What i am trying to figure out is why you can't do it?

Comment: I'll just connect the capacitors in parallel. They only stabilize the voltage and current anyway except c5 which works as a delaying agent.

Comment: The circuit you have drawn can't even start the motor using a power supply, never mind getting it to run with zero power input. Running the motor **consumes power** due to heat and friction losses. To keep it running requires power input. It seems that you have gathered some terminology and concepts but without any understanding. I suggest you study more basic electronics. Tip: You will find that discussing circuits using electron flow is counter-productive. You won't be able to communicate. Just use conventional current the same as everybody else. It works! Some current is due to + ion flow.

Comment: Well, like i said i am a noob in this but this isn't a real perpetual motion device. It is more like a more efficient circuit to run a dc device. The battery in this circuit major purpose is to provide amps while the inductor provides the voltage and emf after a while. To me the only real loss is of voltage which the boost converter provides by using the current provided to it. The circuit will die after the battery is out of current. The reason i am using electron flow is due to the fact that this circuit only requires one terminal.

Comment: D1 and everything to the right are redundant as no current can flow in that branch as there is no **circuit** back to the battery. You haven't fixed C1, C2 and C4 yet so further discussion is pretty much pointless. "*The reason i am using electron flow is due to the fact that this circuit only requires one terminal.*" This is non-sensical. Current flows **in a loop**. You can't get charge out of a battery by connecting to only one terminal.

Comment: I see. Guess i need to hit the books harder. I still have questions but i will eventually answer them myself when my understanding is better. Thank you.

Comment: If you want some shortcuts for what to learn next, voltage, current, resistance, power, ohm's law, watt's law, kirchhoff's law, conservation of matter, conservation of energy, electrical conversion loss and efficiency, capacitance and inductance are all good search terms that will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the positive and negative terminals of your battery to be the high and the low point on a mountain. you have water (electrons) flowing downhill. They turn a water wheel (a lamp) while going down.

Why don't we just dig a channel running uphill? That way, the water will keep flowing and will keep the water wheel spinning. Right?

Electrons don't go from low to high voltage automagically. You need external energy for that. If you want to use a pump (voltage converter) to bring it back up the hill, you need some external power source to do that. IE, you need to power your voltage converter from an external source to get this to work. A battery performs this work with chemical reactions. That is why the power in a battery runs out after a while.